# Looking for a particular dual-track shelving bracket.

Tags: cabinets, shelving, hardware, brackets

I'm considering a dual-track wall shelf system for our living room:

[image]

*(Photo from Home Depot/Rubbermaid)*

I'd also like to hang a few things from the tracks other than shelves. For example, I'd like to hang some ikea cabinets, as well as some vertical plywood for a TV mount.

To do so, I'd like to find some brackets that can be attached to the back of an object and then clipped into the track. Essentially, just the back 1" or so of your standard shelf bracket flared out with screw holes to mount it to a cabinet.

Do such things exist, and, if so, what are they called? I've tried searching for terms such as "dual track cabinet mount" but not having any luck.

Comment: There may be solutions offered, but be very careful of the weight and strain you put on those tracks (often called *standards*). If the tracks are not firmly screwed into studs, do not even consider hanging things like cabinets. Whether they could hold TV mounts depends on the type of mount and the weight of the TV.

Comment: @bib yep. They'll be secured to studs, for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Brackets of the type you want are made. Specifically designed for supporting wall mounted cupboards, white boards, panels etc.

[image]

These were spotted in a UK web site for [SPUR Shelving](http://www.spurshelving.co.uk/). You would have to check if the slot height and spacing on SPUR products matches those of the particular twin slot standards that you are considering.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I'm looking for! Doesn't look like there's a standard name for this, though. Worse case, I'll order from over the pond. Thanks!

Comment: @DA01 - Make sure that your twin slot rails have a slot pitch of 1.25 inches so you could use these adapter plates.

Comment: @DA01 sorry for the comment here on your 7-year old post but I find myself in the same boat as you looking to order these plates. I tried doing so from that UK website but it doesn't seem to work. Were you able to order from them?

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the opening of the wall piece you could use this:

[image]

But you would need to be sure of the objects exact location and adjusting the location would require more modification.

Comment: Interesting, but modifying the wall piece kind of defeats the purpose of the modular system. Odd that these aren't a 'thing'.

Answer (score -1):

here is where you find anything you need

http://www.richelieu.com/ca/en/search/commercial-and-institutional-building-products/commercial-display-hardware/standards-brackets-and-accessories/accessories/1003479?s=shelf+bracket&sort=&nbPerPage=48

Comment: Those aren't for dual track systems

Comment: sorry.  just kind of missed that